# How does the factor $m_b$ arise in the weak effective operator $\mathcal{O}_7^\gamma$?

Tags: standard-model, weak-interaction, effective-field-theory, chirality

According to [1] one of the dominant operators contributing to the decay $B \rightarrow K^{(*)} \ell^+ \ell^-$ is given by $\mathcal{O}_7^\gamma$.

When calculating the coefficient of this operator based on the Standard Model somehow the insertion of the $b$ mass must arise in
$$
  \mathcal{O}_7 = \frac{e}{16 \pi^2} m_b (\bar{s}_L \sigma_{\mu \nu} b_R) F^{\mu \nu} \text{.}
$$
and it must be related to the right-handed $b$ field, but how exactly, what are the consideration to take into account here?

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.06229

Comment: Your reference ***tells you*** at the end of sec 4.1 how chirality flipping operators arise by NP pinching of the first of Fig 2 to the first of Fig 5. Mass terms connect L to R, so a chirality flip term ***must*** be proportional to at least $m_b$ and vanish for vanishing mass... What, specifically, are you after? How many such calculations have you studied?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have not studied a lot of these calculations. In general I know how a matching calculation leads to Wilson coefficients in the effective theory. I also somehow understand that the mass terms couple left- and right-handed fields, so a mass insertion makes sense. But if you asked me to write down a precise calculation that shows how $m_b$ arises, I would not be able to do it, so I guess I do not fully understand what is happening here.

Comment: You are asking for a specific diagram in EFT, then... perhaps ref [25] or an EFT tutorial might be appropriate. Asking for an explicitly worked out paradigm here might be a tall order...

Comment: .... but here is a qualitative [discussion](https://www.quantumdiaries.org/2012/03/19/dissecting-the-penguin/) which might help you....

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed insightful on the qualitative level. I will have a look into [25](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9512380 right?), too, and look for some general EFT introductions. My course on EFTs never spent a word on mass insertions as far as I can remember.